# Key difference between NAVIC Indian Regional Navigation Satellite System (IRNSS) and American Global Positioning System (GPS)?

Tags: gps, navigation

What's the key difference between [NAVIC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oohynJVt4W8) The Indian Regional Navigation Satellite System (IRNSS) and American GPS system?

- Radio Frequency
- Accuracy guaranteed
- Modulation
- Area Covered
- Engineering Parameters

Till now i find a [article](http://www.indiatimes.com/news/india/say-goodbye-to-gps-india-s-all-set-to-switch-to-the-desi-navigation-system-called-indian-regional-navigation-satellite-system-irnss-248186.html) with following points:

- NAVIC Indian Regional Navigation Satellite System or IRNSS
  significantly more accurate than the American GPS system.
- Unlike American GPS, Isro is recommending a small additional hardware
  in handheld devices that can receive S-Band signals from IRNSS
  satellites and inclusion of a code in the phone software to receive
  L-Band signals.
- Both these L and S-band signals received from seven satellite
  constellation of the IRNSS are being calculated by a special embedded
  software which reduces the errors caused by atmospheric disturbances
  significantly. This, in turn, gives a superior quality location
  accuracy than the American GPS system
- It will consist of seven satellites working in tandem to provide
  highly accurate coverage over the Indian subcontinent, up to 1,500 km
  from Indian borders, a region making up the primary service area. [Source](http://thewire.in/2016/01/22/irnss-indias-very-own-gps-19892/)

[image]

Some additional links are https://www.quora.com/What-is-NAVIC and https://www.quora.com/How-useful-is-Indias-GPS-NAVIC-as-compared-to-the-American-GPS

Comment: You seem to have found three differences in those sources. Which do you think is the key one so that you can ask a more focussed question about it, or are you simply looking for the community to give its opinion(s) on which they think is better (which would make this question off-topic)?

Comment: This question would fit nice within final exams in a GNSS course.

Comment: In the news ... http://gpsworld.com/with-irnss-1g-launch-india-completes-and-renames-its-navigation-constellation/

Comment: It looks like those satellites are geostationary (fixed position) and not roaming all round the world like GPS satellites (hence guaranteed accuracy), that's kinda nice for an equatorial or near equatorial region but would be difficult to be implemented for areas more temperate than subtropical. That would be a significant difference.

Comment: To add to the point made by @MichaelStimson, NavIC/IRNSS is `Regional` (hence RNSS, 1,500Kms from Indian boundaries) vs GPS being `Global` (hence GNSS).